# Quotes exercise - how to do ssh inside ssh whilst running sql inside second ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host “sudo su user -c $FOO” type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs)
>   [Wrapping a command that includes single and double quotes for another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command)

I want to run sql over ssh from php . Below command runs nicely

```
ssh server1 "sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c '/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 connect to RATIONAL; /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 set schema Edumate; /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 \"select * from edumate_settings\"'"
```

Now I need to do ssh from server1 to server2 and then run "sudo -u db2inst1 .... " there.

Is there any easy way how to deal with quotes if I add additional server to this scenario? So it will start like

```
ssh server1 "ssh server2 "the rest is as above"
```

Note the I need to run above code from php.

Comment: How come you're not using `ProxyCommand` for SSH forwarding?

Comment: Because I don't know about it :-) Let me check it tomorrow..

Comment: See also [How to enclose in quotes if both single and double quotes are already used?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52775/how-to-enclose-in-quotes-if-both-single-and-double-quotes-are-already-used), [Wrapping a command that includes single and double quotes for another command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get from `command_with_arguments` to
`command "escaped_command_with_arguments"`.
You get `escaped_command_with_arguments` by scanning `command_with arguments` from left to right and replacing each `\` by `\\` and each `"` by `\"`.

alternatively you put `command_with_arguments` in an editor and

1. replace all `\` by `\\`
2. replace each `"` by `\"`

in this order. So step by step you can generate the following sequence of expressions (I used windows notepad to create the expression)

```
select *
db2 "select *"
sudo "db2 \"select *\""
ssh "sudo \"db2 \\\"select *\\\"\""
ssh "ssh \"sudo \\\"db2 \\\\\\\"select *\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
ssh "ssh \"ssh \\\"sudo \\\\\\\"db2 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"select *\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
ssh "ssh \"ssh \\\"ssh \\\\\\\"sudo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"db2 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"select *\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
```

If you count the numbers of `\` before each `"` in the last expression you get the following seuqence:

```
0 1 3 7 15 31 31 15 7 3 1 0
```

or

```
1-1 2-1 4-1 8-1 16-1 32-1 32-1 16-1 8-1 4-1 2-1 1-1
```

So it is possible to construct such a nested expression in one step without iteration, but you must take care how the expressions are nested.

Also these methods can be extended to situations where there are other escaped characters besides `"` and `\`.

So put your command in an editor, replace `server1` by `server2`, replace `\` by `\\` and `"` by `\"` as described above and add `ssh server1 "` at the beginning and `"` at the end and you will get

```
ssh server1 "ssh server2 \"sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c '/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 connect to RATIONAL; /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 set schema Edumate; /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2 \\\"select * from edumate_settings\\\"'\""
```